# How to detect an jquery element is in DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a jquery element. and I remove it from DOM by using remove(), but jQuery still keep a reference of it.

and later I still can use it and insert it into DOM.

How to detect that this "var p" is in DOM or off DOM ?

```
 var p=$('p');
 p.remove();
 console.log(p);
 p.insertAfter($('body'));
```

[image]

I think `p.parent()` is more easy way to go. if it in DOM it will get another DOM node

Comment: `document.contains(p[0])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use javascript length to check if dom element exists or not

```
if($("p").length>0)
{
   // p exists
}
```

Comment: That will return `true` if there are **any** `<p>` elements in the DOM.

Comment: yes, use id to point to particular p, but in this question , he doesnt use id for p :)

Comment: worth mentioning, once he declares `var p=$('p');` he shouldn't use `p.length`  to do this check. He needs to initiate it again with `$('p')`

Comment: This is not a good solution. It only works if you're checking whether **all** `<p>` tags are removed, and it requires you to query the DOM a second time when you already have one or more tags in the variable `p` which you can directly test.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var p=$('p');
 p.remove();
```

So when you did p.remove(), it is removed from the dom but it still exists in memory as a stand alone dom node object with all its contents intact.
You can perform any operation as in normal dom element like append anywhere, change contents or change attributes.
The only difference is that it is not part of the document unless you append it in the html.
jQuery has contains method to check if the element is part of the document

```
jQuery.contains(document, $foo[0]));
```

p.parent() in case of removed p will return a 0 length jquery object because p is independent node and has no parent.